# trigger() not accepting parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, parameters, triggers

**EDIT 4**

Well, I made it work but it's not ideal. I now look to see which class the button has and run the code off of that.  If anyone can figure out how to make it work properly (or atleast explain why it won't) I'd still appreciate it but I'll let this do for now.:

```
$(function () {
    var post = $('ul#filtrifyContainer').find('li'),
    ft = $.filtrify("filtrifyContainer", "placeHolder"),        
    data = $(post).data(),
    genre = $(post).data("genre"),
    number = $(post).data("number");            

    var Filter = function(category){
        $(post).each(function () {
        var attribute = $(this).data(category);             
        $(this).append('<a class="button small ' + category + '">' + attribute.split(',').join('</a><a class="button small ' + category + '">') + '</a>');              

           $('a.button').click(function (e) {
               e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
               var buttonText = $.trim($(this).text());             
               console.log(category);
               console.log(buttonText);                 
               ft.trigger({category: [buttonText]});
           });  
        });         
    };

    if($(this).hasClass('genre')){
        ft.trigger({genre: [buttonText]});
    }   
    if($(this).hasClass('number')){
        ft.trigger({number: [buttonText]});
    }           
});
```

Here's the working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fletchling/JLN6J/13/

**EDIT 3**

I am using [Luis Almeda's Filtrify](http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/) plugin. I am working on printing out the data attribute list within a post, separating the items and turning them into buttons that trigger the filter.  This way, users can filter with the drop down or they can click a button as they browse through items. No scrolling to the top of the page to filter. I have ended up with this code to do this:

```
$(function () {
    var post = $('ul#filtrifyContainer').find('li'),
    ft = $.filtrify("filtrifyContainer", "placeHolder"),        
    data = $(post).data(),
    genre = $(post).data("genre"),
    number = $(post).data("number");            

    var Filter = function(category){
        $(post).each(function () {
        var attribute = $(this).data(category);             
        $(this).append('<a class="button small ' + category + '">' + attribute.split(',').join('</a><a class="button small ' + category + '">') + '</a>');              

           $('a.button').click(function (e) {
               e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
               var buttonText = $.trim($(this).text());             
               console.log(category);
               console.log(buttonText);                 
               ft.trigger({category: [buttonText]});
           });  
        });         
    };

    if(genre)Filter('genre')
    if(number)Filter('number')      
});
```

My problem is that "category" in this line does not accept the parameter and doesn't filter as a result:
    ft.trigger({category: [buttonText]});

The code does work in every other way.  If I replace "category" with the word "genre" or "number" it filters as it should. It also records the correct words in console.log(). When I debug it it shows that "category" is replaced with "number" or "genre". It obviously accepts variables since it reads "buttonText" just fine.  What am I not getting? Why will it not register that particular parameter?  How can I fix this?

You can view my issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/fletchling/JLN6J/10/

You can see where I started below and how I've inched along:

```
$(function () {
    var post = $('ul#filtrifyContainer').find('li'),
    ft = $.filtrify("filtrifyContainer", "placeHolder"),        
    data = $(post).data(),
    genre = $(post).data("genre"),
    number = $(post).data("number");            

    var Filter = function(category){
        $(post).each(function () {
        var attribute = $(this).data(category);             
        $(this).append('<a class="button small ' + category + '">' + attribute.split(',').join('</a><a class="button small ' + category + '">') + '</a>');              

            $('a.button').click(function () {
                var buttonText = $(this).text();                            
                ft.trigger({category: [buttonText]});
                console.log(category);                  
            });     
        });         
    };

if(genre)Filter('genre')
if(number)Filter('number')
```

});

My problem is that when I console.log what category it is it writes out both "genre" and "number".  However, prior to this it only logs the first one.  Why is it doing it now?  I believe this is the only thing keeping it from working and is my last problem.

Scroll all the way to the bottom of the javascript panel to see my code.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I fixed the duplicate attributes pulling up on click with:

```
$('a.button').click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var buttonText = $(this).text();                            
    ft.trigger({category: [buttonText]});
    console.log(category);                  
});
```

And when I debug the code it looks like it's successfully getting pulled into the category on this line:

```
ft.trigger({category: [buttonText]});
```

**EDIT 2:**
Fixed a couple of stupid mistakes. Created var buttonText before e.stopImmediatePropogation and added trim function:

```
$('a.button').click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
    var buttonText = $.trim($(this).text());                
    console.log(category);
    console.log(buttonText);                
    ft.trigger({category: [buttonText]});
});
```